# Why do I have to disable Find my iPhone?

Tags: repair, find-my

According to the page on [preparing your device for repair](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201557), you must turn off Find My iPhone before handing in your phone for repair:

> If you're unable to turn off Find My iPhone, Apple may not be able to service your device. This policy is in force to prevent unauthorized persons from servicing your device without your knowledge.

How does turning off Find My iPhone prevent unauthorised persons from servicing my device?

Answer (score 3):

It prevents people from getting stolen iPhones serviced, because without the AppleID password they can't turn off "Find My iPhone". So your ability to turn it off is actually kind of proove that it is your phone.

I usually do this the moment I hand over the phone in the Store.

Comment: No it doesn't prevent stolen iPhones from getting serviced. I took my wife's phone into get a new battery and didn't know the password. So I tried resetting the AppleID password and I did that successfully. As long as mail and messages are running and available, anyone with an unlocked iPhone can reset the AppleID password. Sooo...